# Read HREF using Jsoup in a Class and Title

Tags: jquery, html

Hi, I have a html file with a long list of `<a class>` tag like this:

```
<a class="tutti" title="Rather Be" href="http://www.angolotesti.it/C/testi_canzoni_clean_bandit_130980/testo_canzone_rather_be_1857037.html"> … </a>
```

I have to read the URL in href for each different title but i'm not able to!

i tried this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.angolotesti.it/top100testi.html").get();
String url = doc.select("a.tutti").first().attr("abs:href");
```

But (obviously) I read always the first url.

Thanks,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.angolotesti.it/top100testi.html").get();
Element link = doc.select("a.tutti").first();
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // return you the url with http://
```

You need to first get the element and then make the request for the URL.

**Tested & Verified**

Comment: ok thanks but my problem is that i have to filter the hrefs by the title!
for example if I have the string "sky" in the tag title the href i should have is
"http://www.angolotesti.it/S/testi_canzoni_author_ANumber/testo_canzone_sky_ANUmber.html"

Comment: I don't want always the first